# IK with pole over subdivided bone chain don't bend

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

Adding IK constraint with target and pole over **subdivided** bone chain don't bend

Steps:

1. Add single bone
2. **Subdivide(W)** in two
3. Extrude from final tail the target and clear parent
4. Add new pole bone in front of first joint
5. Add IK constraint with target. **With this configuration the ik works well**
6. When **pole bone** is added in IK constraint **the joint don't bend**

The bones transformations arent blocked in bone panel. The same configuration with **extruded bones** work well. Where is the blocking configuration option?

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32867)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. This is a bug with the Armature system and may be worth reporting. I think the issue is that it doesn't know which side of the bone is supposed to face the pole target.

However, if you rotate the IK bone **after** moving the target bone, the IK bone will snap to position, and work.

*Rotate*

[image: move target bone]

*Snap*

[image]

Comment: Thank you @CharlesL this way fix the constraint. The bug is reported and confirmed by [developers](https://developer.blender.org/T42617)